# Can I produce small signal gate-source voltage by applying small signal source-drain current?

Tags: mosfet, small-signal

As stated in the title, Can I produce small signal gate-source voltage by applying small signal source-drain current? There is no doubt that I can produce Ids by applying vgs, what about the other way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

When Vds changes, drain-gate capacitance Vdg communicates some current to the gate. Then you have a potential divider formed by Cdg, and the parallel combination of Cgs and the source impedance of the gate drive circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo65Ol.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that this is an AC effect, not observable at DC. More specifically, it is a high frequency effect thanks to the capacitances, and most severe with high speed switching edges, where MOSFETs are commonly used, and increase with increasing voltage.

This can either slow down the switching times, via what is called the Miller effect, or even turn the device on unintentionally when something else modifies Vds at a fast enough rate.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, active elements are "one-way devices" that are controlled from the input side (gate, base, grid); they are not reversible, such as a resistor that can act as both a *voltage-to-current* and *current-to-voltage* converter. But there is a way of connection in which it is possible they to be controlled from the output side (drain, collector, anode) - *by introducing negative feedback*.  Then the input signal that is applied to the output forces the element to adjust its input to provide the output signal. As though, the active element is "reversed".

A typical example of this arrangement is the so-called "active diode" used as an input part of the simple current mirror. In this configuration, the drain is connected to gate and the input current (or voltage through a resistor) is applied to the drain. The transistor adjusts its gate-source voltage to pass the input current through its drain-source part.

Another example is the differential pair where the bias current sink "sucks" the "input" current from the joined sources by the help of this mechanism.